# scanf format specifier to only read a number

Tags: c++, c

Say my input values are:

```
"2a", "6", "-20" "+20"
```

I want to read the following values into an integer:

```
0, 6, -20, 20
```

I'm currently using this line of code:

```
sscanf(input, "%d", &some_integer);
```

but it reads "2a" as having an integer value of 2 - How can I read "2a" as 0?

Comment: You cant! …15 chars…

Comment: Is there any quick way I can manually check for that kind of scenario

Comment: How is your input being fed into the program? Is it a string or is it inputted one at a time? You could split the string into tokens and check if one of your tokens does not contain all digit using isdigit function (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/), if it does not then you could output it as 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this however

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
    char  text[100];
    int   value;
    int   count;
    char *endptr;

    char source[] = "2a 6 -20 +20";
    char *input;

    input = source;
    while (sscanf(input, "%99s%n", text, &count) == 1)
    {
        value = strtol(text, &endptr, 10);
        if (*endptr != '\0')
            value = 0;
        input += count;

        printf("%d ", value);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

1. Use `sscanf()` and the `"%n"` specifier to know how many characters where read and advance the pointer to continue reading.
2. Use `strtol()` to convert the read value to integer, the conversion stops when the first character that is not convertable is found, note that the `base` argument is very important because `2A` is a valid HEX number.
3. Check that the conversion succeeded, if all the characters where converted, `*endptr == '\0'` whill be satisfied.
4. Advance the pointer to the source string, and continue until no more characters are left for reading.

If all you need is to check if the input string is a number, this is what you should use

```
int isdecimal(const char *const text)
{
    char *endptr;
    if (input == NULL)
        return 0;
    /* the 10 is to indicate that the number is in decimal representation */
    strtol(text, &endptr, 10); 
    return (*endptr == '\0')
}
```

if you just want the value to be `0` if it's not convertible, then this is enough

```
int convert(const char *const input)
{
    int   value;
    char *endptr;

    value = strtol(input, &endptr, 10);
    if (*endptr != '\0')
        value = 0;
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you can do this. The `%n` conversion specifier indicates how many characters were consumed by any preceding conversions. It should be the entire string in your case.

```
int convert( char *input )
{
    int some_integer, n;
    if ( sscanf( input, "%d%n", &some_integer, &n ) != 1 )
    {
        printf( "not a number (1)\n" );
        return 0;
    }
    if ( n != strlen(input) )
    {
        printf( "not a number (2)\n" );
        return 0;
    }
    return some_integer;
}

int main( void )
{
    printf( "%d\n", convert( "2a" ) );
    printf( "%d\n", convert( "+20" ) );
}
```